# GroupBy and Count in Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I want to migrate a project from Elasticsearch to Azure Cognitive Search, and I can't find a way to do a group + count operation, such as the Elasticsearch client "aggregate" method. What is the correct way to do it in Azure Search? Ofc I can just get all the data and do the counting in my code (the amount of data in my case is not that big), but there must be a more optimal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use [facets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-faceted-navigation) for that. Though it's more limited than Elasticsearch client "aggregate" method.